# Gitlab CI Child pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a problem with gitlab ci child pipelines.
Need to trigger ci pipeline automatically after each commit in repo that have more than one app. Need to configure to detect which folder/files were modified in order to know which app pipeline to trigger

Example of structure

```
Main/
---- applicationsA/
-------- appA1/
-------- appA2/
-------- appA3/
---- applicationsB/
-------- appB1/
-------- appB2/
-------- appB3/
```

**Main** ".gitlab-ci.yml" is:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: ‘$CI_PIPELINE_SOURE == “web”’

variables:
  APPNAME: $APPNAME

stages:
  - child-pipelines

appA1:
  stage: child-pipelines
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: applicationA/appA1/gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - if: $APPNAME == “appA1” && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURE == “web”

appA2:
  stage: child-pipelines
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: applicationA/appA2/gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - if: $APPNAME == “appA1” && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURE == “web”
...
```

**appA1** ".gitlab-ci.yml" is:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test

build-appA1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Execute appA1 build!"

publish-appA1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Execute appA1 publish!"
```

appA2 ".gitlab-ci.yml" is:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test

build-appA2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Execute appA1 build!"

publish-appA2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Execute appA1 publish!"
```

The purpose of this configuration is that , for example, when i change a file inside app**, the pipeline detects the changes and build the app**.

Comment: Something off with the quotes `“`. `I have a problem` What problem?

Comment: there are different keywords in Gitlab CI/CD like when, you should take a look at those that can help. [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rules:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) with a glob pattern and only run a certain job if anything changes in the specific app folder:

```
appA1:
  stage: child-pipelines
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: applicationA/appA1/gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - if: '$APPNAME == "appA1" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURE == "web"'
      changes:
        - Main/applicationsA/appA1/**/*
```

Comment: Thank you for you response.
Is it possible to use rules:changes with rules: if: $APPNAME == “appA1” && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURE == “web”?

Comment: @CatLover yes it is. I updated my answer