# Gitlab CI automatical run pipeline on merge request

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

I have below pipeline.
After creating merge request, created **Detached merge request pipeline** with **failed** status (app1 - no stages/jobs).
In scope of below pipeline need to run pipeline when merge request is created and after merging changes main. Flow described in here [Gitlab CI Child pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250843/gitlab-ci-child-pipeline)
Below pipeline does not work.

```yaml
workflow:
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'

stages:
    - child-pipelines

app1:
    stage: child-pipelines
    variables:
        COMPONENT NAME: 'app1'
    trigger:
        include:
        - local: .ci/.gitlab-ci.yml
        strategy: depend
    rules:

        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
          changes:
            - test1/**/*
          variables:
            DEPLOY_RELEASE: '11111'

        - if : '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
          changes:
            - test1/**/*
          variables:
            DEPLOY_RELEASE: '222222'
app2:
    stage: child-pipelines
    variables:
        COMPONENT NAME: 'app1'
    trigger:
        include:
        - local: .ci/.gitlab-ci.yml
        strategy: depend
    rules:

        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
          changes:
            - test2/**/*
          variables:
            DEPLOY_RELEASE: '11111'

        - if : '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
          changes:
            - test2/**/*
          variables:
            DEPLOY_RELEASE: '222222'
```

Comment: your `changes:` rule might prevent this from working as you expect. Unlike MR pipelines which evaluate the entire changeset, pushes only test the very last commit being pushed to evaluate `changes:`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run a pipeline when merge request was created and after merge to main branch, take a look this example:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
    
job1:
  script:
    - echo "This job runs in merge request and also after merge to main branch"
```

According to [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html).

If you want to run a rule for the entire pipeline:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  
job1:
  script:
    - echo "This job runs in merge request pipelines"
    
job2:
  script:
    - echo "This job also runs in merge request pipelines"
```

If you want to run a rule in certain job:

```yaml
job1:
  script:
    - echo "This job runs in merge request pipelines"
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Comment: Thanks. but this is not my case )

Comment: @CatLover, please, take a look the updated comment. I just checked on Gitlab CICD and it works after merge request and also after merge to main branch.

Comment: What about           changes:
            - test/**/*
          variables:
            DEPLOY_RELEASE: '11111'

Comment: @AlejandroNortes I tried your example is there a way that I should run the pipeline only after a branch is merged to develop? currently it runs when it is created and after its merged

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same issue with the same setting, i.e., triggering a child pipeline only when a merge request is created/updated and only if files in specific paths are changed.

I solved it in a way I don't understand but that works

In added the following at the beginning of the child `.gitlab-ci.yml` (in your case `.ci/.gitlab-ci.yml`):

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - when: always
```

I think by default pipelines are triggered only for pushes, and since we force the parent pipeline to be executed on merge requests, the child pipeline has to specifically allow it as well (or, in this case, to be executed in any situation).