# Is it possible to run a gitlab pipeline job only once, when a merge request is created?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-pipelines, merge-request

Is it possible to configure a job in a gitlab pipeline to only run once, when a merge request is created?

Using the rule "

```
'$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

" does not work, as it will also be triggered when there are new commits to the branch with the open merge request.

Comment: Is this [similar to that question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71355435/6309)?

Comment: Sadly it's not, this pipelines will run on any commit when a merge request is open. I am looking for a way to only run a pipeline job on the creation of a merge request

Answer (score 0):

You can use workflow to manage your pipeline. For example:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
```

This workflow will only be triggered when merge, default branch commit, schedule